# QEMU GPU passthrough, how is that even possible?

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu

I saw on internet that we can pass physical video card to guest machine. but how can that be possible?

for example :

if we have following machine:

```
CPU: intel 7700k with HD Graphics 630
RAM: 16G
GPU: Nvidia GrForce 1070
```

The integrated GPU is HD Graphics 630, I want the qemu host linux to use this one, and pass nvidia card to guest windows. but I have only one monitor which is plugged to a DisplayPort on the nvidia card, if I pass nvidia card to guest windows, then my host linux will have no display, isn't it?

Comment: Does your QEMU support VirGL?

Comment: Of you are doing a passthrough of some device, it is assumed the host does not use it. If you are have a dual video card, you have to guarantee the host does not use it and the virtualization solution does it.

Comment: If your monitor supports dvi and hdmi you could use one cable connection for each card.

Comment: If your monitor has multiple video inputs (or you have multiple monitors), plug one into your dGPU, the other into your motherboard. Your host will use the one connected to your motherboard, the guest will use the one plugged into your dGPU

Comment: Not all is linear. While my corporate notebook is an i6 the chipset seems too old to support vga passthrough